# Java 64bit install throwing non compatible 64bit error in 64bit Windows 7

Tags: java, installation, 64-bit

JRE and JDK 64bit install executable are throwing a non compatible win32 error:

> jre_7u1_windows-x64bit.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

I thought this could be a system environment variable problem, but from what I can tell it is not, the variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` is set as:

```
AMD64
```

and the variable `PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER` is set as:

`Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel`

I am not sure what variables the installer reads from if any.

I have tried the Java 6 installer and the same thing. I can install other programs designed for a 64bit architecture and I have looked at Control Panel>System and Security>System: which is in fact "*System type: 64-bit Operating System*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the file that you downloaded is *corrupted*. Check that it downloaded completely, or try to use another browser to download the installer. Unfortunately there are no checksums on the JRE download pages.

Also check the digital signature is valid and shows no warning: open the properties dialog of the installer and then click *Digital Signatures* tab.

Comment: Thank you so much I was using Firefox to download it, but I tried Internet Explorer and it downloaded correctly. I think the problem is my "https everywhere" plugin I use with Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

You can only run a 64bit JVM on a 64bit operating system.  It sounds like you are trying to run it on a 32bit Windows operating system.

---

The fact that the hardware is 64bit capable is not sufficient to run executables in 64bit mode.  For that to happen, you *also* need to run a 64bit capable operating system; i.e. one that understands how to deal with user processes with 64 bit virtual address spaces.

Comment: Just because the CPU is 64 bit it doesn't really mean that his OS is 64 bit as well.

Comment: I have added a sentence to the last paragraph of my question explaining that I am in fact using a 64bit OS. Sorry I left this out last night, but I was dead tired when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

The error points out that you are probably using a 32 bit windows.

Go to your system control, choose system. It should show you if you are on 32 or 64 bit.

Here is a microsoft guide for figuring out if your OS is 64 bit or not: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218/en-us

Comment: I have added a sentence to the last paragraph of my question explaining that I am in fact using a 64bit OS. Sorry I left this out last night, but I was dead tired when I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be existence of java exe files in "C:\ProgramData\Oracle" folder.

If you delete Java folder inside Oracle folder, it will resolve the issue.

Hope this helps.